# Can someone explain this objective C statement

Tags: objective-c

I don't understand what is going on here, I am trying to use regex and I am really confused by the following.

```
BOOL isMatch = match != nil;
```

The full code is

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a-z0-9_]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
BOOL isMatch = match != nil;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a basic C statement involving a variable assignment (on the left of the `=`) and an expression (on the right of the `=`).

Let's start with the right side:

```
match != nil;
```

This expression is evaluated. The `!=` operator (not-equal or unequal) evaluates to either true or false. If `match` has been assigned to a non-nil value, it is true. If it has not been assign a `nil` value, it is false.

This true or false result is then assigned to the `BOOL` variable. A true result is `YES` and  false result is `NO`.

So in English, the statements says:

> If match has a non-nil value, `isMatch` is `YES`, otherwise it is `NO`.

Answer (score 2):

It might be clearer if we use some parentheses:

```
BOOL isMatch = (match != nil);
```

That is, if `match` is not `nil`, `isMatch` will be true (`YES`).

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL isMatch = match != nil;
```

is a shorter way to write

```
BOOL isMatch;
if(match != nil)
{
  isMatch = YES; // You found a match!
}
else
{
  isMatch = NO; // No match found :(
}
```

Comment: You should use `YES` and `NO` with `BOOL`.

Answer (score 0):

break it up into bits, think about if you put `match != nil` into an if statement, but instead assigning the result to a bool